# htaccess condition destroys other images and pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm using the below htaccess code, so that when users type www.current_website.com/go  or www.current_website.com/go/  they go to another website www.other_website.com

```
RewriteRule go http://www.other_website.com
RewriteRule go/ http://www.other_website.com
```

the problem is the logo.jpg image coz' it contains go  didn't appear
the logout.php page (contains go also) when accessed in current_website, it goes to www.other_website.com

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `go` is all there is by anchoring it to the start and the end. I also made the slash optional so that you only need 1 rule:

```
RewriteRule ^go/?$ http://www.other_website.com
                 ^ the end of the path
               ^^ optional slash
            ^ the start of the path
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use?

```
RewriteRule http://www.current_website.com/go http://www.other_website.com
RewriteRule http://www.current_website.com/go/ http://www.other_website.com
```